# I cannot get posted body in revel go framework

Tags: rest, curl, go, revel

I am trying to implement a basic CRUD using the Rest architecture in revel, but I am not able to send the data encoded in `json` format to an endpoint, I was try multiple ways to check the body content in the request, so now I have a "minimal compilable example":

1. create a new project using revel cli tool.
2. Apply the following changes

   ```
   diff --git a/app/controllers/app.go b/app/controllers/app.go
   index 1e94062..651dbec 100644
   --- a/app/controllers/app.go
   +++ b/app/controllers/app.go
   @@ -9,5 +9,6 @@ type App struct {
    }

    func (c App) Index() revel.Result {
   -   return c.Render()
   +   defer c.Request.Body.Close()
   +   return c.RenderJSON(c.Request.Body)
    }
   diff --git a/conf/routes b/conf/routes
   index 35e99fa..5d6d1d6 100644
   --- a/conf/routes
   +++ b/conf/routes
   @@ -7,7 +7,7 @@ module:testrunner
    # module:jobs


   -GET     /                                       App.Index
   +POST     /                                       App.Index

    # Ignore favicon requests
    GET     /favicon.ico                            404
   ```
3. do a POST request:

   ```
   curl --request POST --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Accept: application/json" --data '{"name": "Revel framework"}' http://localhost:9000
   ```

My problem; the curl call does not give me an echo back (the same `json` `{"name": "Revel framework"}`), so what I am missing to use revel correctly?

PS: I can find some other related links to this problem but they do not work for me. For example this: https://github.com/revel/revel/issues/126

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [source of Revel](https://github.com/revel/revel/blob/v0.17.1/params.go#L63), when the request content type is either `application/json` or `text/json`, the content of request body is automatically read from stream and stored to [c.Params.JSON](https://godoc.org/github.com/revel/revel#Params) which has type `[]byte`.

Since the [Request.Body](https://godoc.org/net/http#Request) is a stream which can only be read once, you cannot read it again (and anyway, your code won't work even if Revel does not automatically read the stream, since `c.Request.Body` is not correctly serialiazable using`c.RenderJSON()`).

Revel has convenient function [Params.BindJSON](https://godoc.org/github.com/revel/revel#Params.BindJSON) which converts `c.Params.JSON` to the golang object.

Here's sample code.

```
type MyData struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

func (c App) Index() revel.Result {
    data := MyData{}
    c.Params.BindJSON(&data)
    return c.RenderJSON(data)
}
```